# Why does my SQL Server decimal division give me a scale of 6 digits?

Tags: sql-server, casting, type-conversion, precision

I am new to SqlServer and using SQLServer2019. I have learnt about CAST() and CONVERT() built-in functions. Now I'm confused why my code is giving scale of 6.

```
DECLARE @num1 AS int = 4;
DECLARE @num2 AS int = 127;
select @num2/Convert(decimal(5,2), @num1) as 'Div result';
select CONVERT(decimal(4,2), @num1);
select CAST(@num1 as decimal(4,2));
```

result of the above sql query is:

```
31.750000

4.00

4.00
```

I am trying to scale the division result upto 3 decimal places but it's not working.

Line 4 and 5 is working as i'm expecting but why line 3 is behaving like this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check up the table on the [precision, scale and length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) page. You won't get less than 6 unless you have massive precision values.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I beg to differ: Since the formula is `max(6, ...)`, you will *never* get less than 6 for divisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the SQL Server documentation, for decimal division, the scale of the resulting value is:

```
max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)
```

In your case, that's `max(6, 0 + 5 + 1) = 6`.

Source: [Precision, Scale, and Length (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms190476(v=sql.90))

Comment: But @Heinzi i have used scale = 2, precision=5, then should be like (max, 2+5+1) = 8.
Isn't it? Or i'm getting something wrong. please correct me. I'm confused.

Comment: Thank you @Heinzi for your help and the link.. I understood the solution

Comment: @Anupamdatta: You got it backwards: s1 refers to the scale of the *first* number. Since you divide `@num2/...`, s1 refers to the scale of `@num2`. `@num2` is an integer, which has a scale of 0.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms190476(v=sql.90))  I understood the answer.

I didn't mentioned the precision for @num1 so it took default precision for decimal which is zero, therefore s1=0

precision for @num2 = 5, so, p2=5

therefor max(6, s1+p2+1) => max(6, 0+5+1) = 6

And hence it was showing scale of 6 in the answer.